# How to access Vuex root mutation from a module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Hi I am planning to split my current Vuex store into 3 modules

1. auth - user login/logout/registration
2. posts - add/delete/update post
3. image - update/delete images

All actions in these 3 modules will call a SET_ERROR mutation which updates the error. I will keep SET_ERROR mutation and error state in the root store. But how can I call the root mutation from inside my modules?

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

Comment: Thanks I'm guessing we pass { root: true } to access root mutation. I will try that now.

Comment: @JaromandaX how would I access state inside a module which exists in another module? e.g. const filePath = `images/${context.state.user._id}/${file.name}` - (before refactor). How would I get the user state from my auth module?

Comment: I can't tell from one line of code - sorry

Comment: Looks like const filePath = `images/${context.rootState.auth.user._id}/${file.name}` worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is to add `{root: true}` as the 3rd argument in your call to commit a mutation, as is visible on line 26 - where `commit("setError"` is called at the end. This tells Vuex that the mutation should start with the root of the store.

This also works for cross-module communication, committing mutations from one namespaced store to another (although actions may be more appropriate to do that in most cases).

Below is an example of your store setup, minimized into a single namespaced module (auth) and I made up an action and a couple mutations just as an example.

```js
{
  state: {
    error: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    setError(state, message) {
      state.error = message;
    },
  },
  modules: {
    auth: {
      namespaced: true,
      state: { user: null },
      mutations: {
        setUser(state, user) {
          state.user = user;
        },
      },
      actions: {
        async logIn({ commit, dispatch, rootState }) {
          try {
            let response = await fetch("/login");
            let data = await response.json();
            commit("setUser", data);
          } catch (err) {
            commit("setError", err.message, { root: true });
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```